# Laravel 5.2 make:auth add one more register form

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I want to customize the built in auth feature. Namely i want to add one more Register form beside the one that is built in. like on this picture:

[image]

When i click on Registrieren Endkunde i get the built in form from laravel

[image]

And i just duplicated that view file register.blade.php by making a new file in that same folder /resources/views/auth/registrieren-ag.blade.php and changed only a few things inside so that it says Registrieren Agentur.
But when i click on homepage on the link Registrieren Agentur i get this error message:

[image]

And this is my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

And these are all the routes with command php artisan route:list

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name | Action                                                          | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                       |      | Closure                                                         | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                    |      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                       | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest  |
|        | POST     | login                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                  |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 | web        |
|        | POST     | password/email          |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest  |
|        | POST     | password/reset          |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | web,guest  |
|        | POST     | register                |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | web,guest  |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Now, the question is how to add this route when registrieren-ag.blade.php is called and to be functional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted everything and started from scratch (now the new register form is called registrieren.blade.php) What i did is only added a new route into routes.php file:

```
Route::get('/registrieren', function() {
    return view('auth.registrieren');
});
```

And it works it opens it...i just need to test it if it really registers a user through that form!

It works...i just tested it! Sooo the solution for adding an extra register form:

1. php artisan make:auth
2. go to your /resources/views/auth/register.blade.php and duplicate that file (to make a new register form which you can adjust and edit as you like)
3. go to /resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php and find

   ```
   <!-- Authentication Links -->
                   @if (Auth::guest())
                       <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                       <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                   @else
   ```
4. add a new link to your new created register form for example:

   ```
      <li><a href="{{ url('/registernew') }}">Register NEW</a>
   ```

remember that the name 'registernew' must be the same as your duplicated form view (registernew.blade.php)

5. inside your new form view registernew.blade.php change the line

   ```
    <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
   ```

And that should be it....you can add new form fields and customize the database table to correspond to that form fields and you can have different users in the same table and make use of that as roles!

Answer (score 0):

Please show the methods showRegistrationForm and register in Auth\AuthController because there need to change  `return view('register');` onto `return view('registrieren-ag');`

Comment: where are those methods?? here is my AuthController file i copied it on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q4j3cx78/

Comment: Here it is: /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php   @dfinchenko so you are saying i need to add methods for redirecting the users to my new page registrieren-ag.blade.php

Comment: Ok, I suggest add to route.php 'Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');' and add to AuthController method which return registration form 'public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('registrieren-ag');
    }' and delete or comment 'Route::auth();'

Comment: Here are the methods in this file http://paste.ofcode.org/8afGZyyNSUL3bJb4ZBk6bA    so what do i need to add here to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Route::auth() is a shortcut to defining the following routes:

```
$this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
$this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

$this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

$this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: in Laravel 5.2 those routes are gone....how can i override some of them???  for example if i go to Auth\AuthController.php can i write my own method for register?? and where are those built in methods now, because everything is working fine but the methods are not inside Auth\AuthController.php

Answer (score 0):

In this method

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    if (property_exists($this, 'registerView')) {
        return view($this->registerView);
    }

    return view('auth.register');
}
```

you need to change  `return view('auth.register');` onto  `return view('auth.registrieren-ag');`

Comment: But that would override the existing view for registration...i need a new method for another register form! so i think i should add a new function showRegistrationAgForm () { ... } e.g. isn't that right?

Comment: I tried to do it but i get errors always... the problem is deeper than i thought...if anyone can solve this please???

Comment: Please show your errors and what you add to route and controller